# Baremetal not available in dal10 according to api

Tags: api, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

An excerpt from call, https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Product_Package/getAllObjects

```
{
"firstOrderStepId": 1,
"id": 50,
"isActive": 1,
"keyName": "BARE_METAL_INSTANCE",
"name": "Bare Metal Instance",
"unitSize": 1
},
```

Using this id I make call: https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Product_Package/50/getRegions
dal01, dal05, dal06, dal07 and dal09 are returned but dal10 is not. This explains the error I am getting when attempting to verify a BM order in dal10:

`The location provided for this order is invalid. (HTTP 200)`

If I use the UI I can order bare metals in dal10. Why can I not do this through the api?

Hardware template I am using:

```
hardwareTpl = datatypes.Hardware{
        Datacenter: &datatypes.Location{Name: sl.String("dal10")},
        Domain: sl.String("xxx"),
        Hostname: sl.String("xxx"),
        HourlyBillingFlag: sl.Bool(false),
        MemoryCapacity: sl.Uint(32),
        OperatingSystemReferenceCode: sl.String("UBUNTU_16_64"),
        PrimaryBackendNetworkComponent: &datatypes.Network_Component{Id: sl.Int(vlanPriId), MaxSpeed: sl.Int(10000)},
        PrimaryNetworkComponent: &datatypes.Network_Component{Id: sl.Int(vlanPubId), MaxSpeed: sl.Int(10000)},
        ProcessorCoreAmount: sl.Uint(4),
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is correct, the UI uses other packages to order Bare Metal servers, I recommend to use this request:

```
https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Product_Package_Server/getAllObjects
```

That is gonna return all the packages that the UI displays

Comment: Thank you. How can I configure my datatypes.Hardware object to use one of these packageIds? My Hardware object is above and currently auto sets the packageId to 50 when I pass it to GenerateOrderTemplate

Comment: ohhh you are using the createObject Method, I am afraid that you cannot change the package ID using that method you need to use the placeOrder method I recommend you to read this https://softlayer.github.io/blog/bpotter/going-further-softlayer-api-python-client-part-3/ to understand how to order like the UI does

Comment: Thanks Nelson, this does seem like what I need. I started through the guide but reached another blocker. Was wondering if you could help again? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50223233/response-from-getconfiguration-does-not-return-itemcategory-information