# Response from GetConfiguration does not return ItemCategory information

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

The api call I am using is: https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Product_Package/257/getConfiguration
The type returned from this call is an array of Product_Package_Order_Configuration:
https://github.com/softlayer/softlayer-go/blob/master/datatypes/product.go#L1413

The issue I am seeing is that in the response, the ItemCategory field is always nil. I am not using a mask so I would think everything should be returned.

Is there some way I can modify this call to have it return ItemCategory as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The itemCategory is a relational property and this belongs to another datatype, so you need to use object-masks over the getConfiguration method if you want to retrieve this data.

For more information you can see the following documentation:

```
https://softlayer.github.io/reference/datatypes/SoftLayer_Product_Package_Order_Configuration/
```

You can use this rest api to get the item categories:

Method: GET

```
https://[username]:[apiKey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Product_Package/257/getConfiguration?objectMask=mask[itemCategory]
```

Another way to get the categories is throuth the method "getCategories" of the same service.

You can use the following rest api:

Method: GET

```
https://[username]:[apiKey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Product_Package/257/getCategories
```

Reference:

```
https://softlayer.github.io/reference/services/SoftLayer_Product_Package/getCategories/
```